# The default fontfamily ignored when I use textTheme argument, Is that default behavior's of flutter? Or any correction in my code?

Tags: flutter

So Here is the code and the output below, I used 'Raleway' font for whole app default font-family and that's font applied if **textTheme** is not set. After setting up textTheme the whole application's font styling and font-family changed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './categories_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'DeliMeal App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.pink)
            .copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber),
        canvasColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 250, 1),
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        // textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(),
      ),
      home: const CategoriesScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

before applying the textTheme argument : -

[image]

after applying the textTheme argument : -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. It's like inline and external css in html. Here is an example :

```html
Text(
            'Hello World',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                ),
          )
```

Since the changing fontfamily process here is more specific than the process in theme so the font will be Raleway for other texts and Helvetica for this text. In summary, the order is as follows : theme > text theme > text style ..

Comment: This is not type of answer that I am looking for, And I know there is no error in this app, I would like to know why the default fontFamily applied in theme argument not worked when any textTheme style applied to the app which clearly shown above images of app the styling of the all the text is changed.